# GSP - set integer values for select tag option

Tags: grails, gsp

In My GSP  i have a select tag

```
<g:select  from="${named}" name="name"  noSelection="['':'-Select-']"  ></g:select>
```

which produced HTML

```
<select name="name" id="name">
 <option value="">-Select-</option>
 <option value="USA">USA</option>
 <option value="UK">UK</option>
```

but i need to have integer value there starting from 1 (i,e USA wil have value 1 and UK 2)

How do i do it

Answer (score 2):

one solution could be that before you return the list to your gsp, convert your list to a map and define the indexes for the countries, so that you have a result like for example..

```
def named = ["USA","UK"]
def namedMap = [:]
named.eachWithIndex() {obj, i -> namedMap.put(++i, obj) }
```

which would give a result like

```
def namedMap = [1:"USA",2:"UK"]
```

and in your GSP you can do like:

```
<g:select optionKey="key" optionValue="value" 
    name="name" noSelection="['':'-Select-']" from="${namedMap}" />
```

Comment: You can also do `def namedMap = [1..named.size(), named].transpose().collectEntries()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this..,.

```
<select name="name">
    <g:each in="${named}" var="country" status="idx">
        <option value="${idx + 1}">${country}</option>
    </g:each>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set **option key** in your g:select tag like this ...

```
<g:select id="name" name="name" from="${name}" optionKey="id" optionValue="${{it.name}}" value="${named}" />
```